# Showing the function=? is impossible

Tags: undecidability, lambda-calculus, halting-problem

Here's a lab from a first-year computer science course, taught in Scheme: https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs135/assns/a07/a07.pdf

At the end of the lab, it basically presents the halting problem, and shows that it is impossible to solve by introducing the function `diagonal`, which is defined as:

```
(deﬁne (diagonal x)
  (cond
     [(halting? x x) (eternity 1)]
     [else true]))
```

Where `eternity` is a non-terminating program defined as `(define (eternity x) (eternity x))`. What happens when you feed `diagonal` its own definition as input ... ?

This is all fairly standard stuff. Then, the lab says:

> For a real challenge, deﬁnitively answer the question posed at the end of Exercise 20.1.3 of the
>   text, with the interpretation that function=? consumes two lists representing the code for the two
>   functions. This is the situation Church considered in his proof.

So the gist of it is that `function=?` takes two inputs. Each is a list, which represents the definition of a function, i.e. it is a list of the form `(define (id args ...) body ...)`. We can assume that both functions are syntactically valid and will terminate for all inputs (without runtime errors). `function=?` returns true if and only if the two functions will always return the same result when given the same inputs. For example,

```
(function=? '(define (foo x) (* 2 x)) 
            '(define (bar x) (+ x x))) ; should return #t

(function=? '(define (foo x) (+ x 1)) 
            '(define (bar x) (+ x 2))) ; should return #f
```

Now, `function=?` is obviously impossible to write - the challenge is to *prove* it is impossible. I thought about this for a while, and the best solution I could come up with is the following:

```
(define (disprove-function=? x)
  ((lambda (snip)
     (let ((self (list 'define '(disprove-function=? x)
                       (list snip (list 'quote snip)))))
       (if (function=? self '(define (id x) x))
           (list x)
           x)))
   '(lambda (snip) 
      (let ((self (list 'define '(disprove-function=? x)
                        (list snip (list 'quote snip)))))
        (if (function=? self '(define (id x) x))
            (list x)
            x)))))
```

Basically, `disprove-function=?` uses standard quining techniques to generate its own source code (the variable `self`), and then asks `function=?` if it is equivalent to the identity function. If `function=?` says #f, then `disprove-function=?` will always behave like the identity function. Contradiction! If `function=?` says #t, then `disprove-function=?` will always behave differently from identity; in particular, it will behave like the `list` function. Contradiction! Thus, `function=?` can't exist. QED.

My question is: is there a more elegant way to approach this problem? My solution seems ... long and ugly. Not nearly as nice as the `diagonal` function for proving that the halting problem is unsolvable.

NB: Please give me answers and not hints! Even though this is a homework question, it is not *my* homework question: I don't go to this university! Further, as you can see from the lab, this question is under the `Enhancements` category and isn't worth marks, so even if you don't believe me, there is still no problem with just giving me an answer. Finally, I already *have* a solution, which I am pretty sure is right; I was just wondering if there was a *better* solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the halting problem seems like the good solution. Suppose you have a function `red` that takes the code of a function (or [λ-term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untyped_lambda_calculus#Computable_functions_and_lambda_calculus)) (or a untyped function), reduces one step (or [β-redex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untyped_lambda_calculus#Beta_reduction)) in it and returns the code of the resulting function. Suppose also that you have a function `normal` that says if the term is in [normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_normal_form).

In Turing machines language, `red` would be the computation of one step and `normal` would return true when we are in a final state.

Let's simulate the computation of $n$ steps, returning $43$ instead of $1$ if we reach the end of the computation:

```
(define (run t n)
  (if (= n 0) 1
    (if (normal t) 43
      (run (red t) (n-1)))))
```

Then we can decide if the execution of a term will terminate or not:

```
(define (one x) 1)
(define (terminate t) (not (function=? (run t) one)))
```

From that we can use the usual diagonal argument:

```
(define (loop x) (loop x))
(define (f x) (if (terminate (code-of-application x (quote x))) (loop 0) 1)
(f code-of-f)
```

If `f` terminates on `code-of-f` then `(terminate (code-of-application code-of-f (quote code-of-f))` will return `true` and then `f` will loop on `code-of-f`. So it should loop. Then `(terminate ...)` should return `false` and `f` will terminate on `code-of-f`, contradiction.

Technicalities: one need to define a base language which is expressive enough to be able to write everything is written above. You then need `red` and `normal` which can be tougher than one can imagine. You need also the standard quine techniques: `quote` which, given the code of a term, returns a term representing the code of the term, `code-of-application a b` is easy and self-explanatory, and of course you need to write everything above internally to write `code-of-f`.

The lambda-calculus is surprisingly simple and expressive to both write all this down and to prove its correctness, which is why Church used it to solve [Hilbert's tenth problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem), but one can do it in a lot of languages, possibly in a simpler way, using language-specific quine tricks.